# Role X does not exist. Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I use asp.net identity in my project.I can create role i dont have problem with rolemanager.But i can't add my user to role.When i try user to add Editor role i take this error.How can i find whats wrong  ?

```
Role Editor does not exist.
```

But when i use this code i can see Editor role in list

var roles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();

My Code:

```
    public void UpdateRole(ApplicationUser uyeApplicationUser, string role)
    {
        var roles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
        UyeManager.AddToRole(uyeApplicationUser.Id, role);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved my problem My Role name is Editor and when sql server use UPPER funtion it cannot find Editor.

```
SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[Id]   AS [Id],
               [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM   [dbo].[AspNetRoles] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  ((UPPER([Extent1].[Name])) = (UPPER('Editor' /* @p__linq__0 */)))
        OR ((UPPER([Extent1].[Name]) IS NULL)
            AND (UPPER('Editor' /* @p__linq__0 */) IS NULL))
```

Comment: What was the actual solution to this? Renaming your roles?